# Get value from textbox and output it

Tags: javascript

How to get value from `myTextbox` and output to `<p>`?

Why I got the error message: `[object HTMLInputElement]`

```
<input type="text" id="myTextbox">
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Run" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="myOutput"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
    document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error message because **`x` is an `object`**. This means that he **is complex** (textbox have `value`, `name`, `onclick`, etc) and don't know how/what to be represented as `string`. The result is his `type` `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

To get the **`value` of the `object`** you have to acces `x.value` property.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
    document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML = x.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextbox">
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Run" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="myOutput"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract data from control you have to use `.value`

Try like this

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML = x.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the text in the input using `.value`:

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextbox">
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Run" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="myOutput"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
    document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML = x.value;
}
</script>
```

---

For fun, you can update the `<p>` automatically:

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextbox" onchange="myFunction()" onkeyup="this.onchange();">
<p id="myOutput"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
    document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML = x.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch value of textbox and then feed it to the paragraph tag.
You got the error because you are trying to insert textbox in paragraph.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox");
    document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML = x.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextbox">
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Run" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="myOutput"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="myTextbox">
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Run" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="myOutput"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.querySelector("#myTextbox");
        document.querySelector("#myOutput").innerHTML = x.value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the value of the [input field](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp), Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/y965zs5v/)

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTextbox").value;
```